# A table where each cell is the sum of the two cells that are its top and left neighbors

Tags: terminology, math-history

What is the name of this table? I am looking for a name such as "Fibonacci sequence". I am assuming my table already has a name, but I guess it is possible that I invented it. Here is what it looks like:
$$
\begin{array}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\hline 1 & 3 & 6 & 10 & 15 & 21 \\
\hline 1 & 4 & 10 & 20 & 35 & 56 \\
\hline 1 & 5 & 15 & 35 & 70 & 126 \\
\hline 1 & 6 & 21 & 56 & 126 & 252 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Basically, the table is started by entering the number 1 in all the cells of the first column and the first row. Then, each cell is the sum of its up+left neighbor. So, cell (2,2) has value 2. Cell (2,3) has value 3. Etc.

UPDATE: The best answer so far is that it is basically Pascal's triangle but on a slant. I doubt there's a more specific name for it than that.

Comment: Pascal's triangle, viewed at a slant?

Comment: @kimchilover yes that's a great answer! Hoping there's a slightly more specific name but that definitely works for my purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called a [*symmetric Pascal matrix*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_matrix).